# TensorFlow: apply convolutions along one specific axis

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two tensors `A` and `B` of shape `(batch_size, height, width, 1)` which I want to convolve along the `width` axis, i.e. convolve `A[0, 0]` with `B[0, 0]`, `A[0, 1]` with `B[0, 1]`, `A[3, 6]` with `B[3, 6]`, etc. I've tried to achieve this with a combination of [`tf.nn.conv1d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv1d) and [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn), but I keep getting errors related to the input shapes, AutoGraph, etc.

How do I efficiently convolve these two tensors along a specific axis?

EDIT: added non-functional code to illustrate the idea

```
# Create tensors
A, B = tf.random.normal(shape=(2, 1, 8, 512, 1))

# Reshape tensors suitable for `conv1d`
A = tf.transpose(A, [1, 0, 2, 3])
B = tf.transpose(B, [1, 2, 0, 3])

# Define convolution function
conv_fn = partial(tf.nn.conv1d, padding="SAME", stride=1)

# Apply map
AB = tf.map_fn(lambda x: conv_fn(x[0], x[1]), (A, B))
```

Result (vector values omitted for brevity):

```
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.

First structure: type=tuple str=(<tf.Tensor: shape=(8, 1, 512, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[omitted]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(8, 512, 1, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[omitted]], dtype=float32)>)

Second structure: type=EagerTensor str=tf.Tensor(
[[omitted]], shape=(1, 512, 1), dtype=float32)

More specifically: Substructure "type=tuple str=(<tf.Tensor: shape=(8, 1, 512, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[omitted]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(8, 512, 1, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[omitted]], dtype=float32)>)" is a sequence, while substructure "type=EagerTensor str=tf.Tensor(
[[omitted]], shape=(1, 512, 1), dtype=float32)" is not
```

Comment: what do you mean with "i want to convolve"? convolution is not well defined for 2 elements (also, please try to describe step by step, for example with a pseudo code, what you want to achieve)

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia the tensors are of shape `(batch_size, height, width, 1)`, so `A[0, 0]` is of shape `(width, 1)` (and same for `B`), so the convolution between the two is well defined

Comment: I'm not saying that is illformed, I'm saying that is not clear what you mean by convoluting two elements. There is a reason if the TF conv function accepts 1 input, and that is because convolution is defined on one input... probably if you post the code you used in the map_fn callback, might be much clearer what you want to achieve, even if that does not work

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I've added some code to illustrate the point

Comment: why are you using conv1d? your filters B are clearly 2d...

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia No, the filters are 1D (the summation should not be performed along the `height` axis). You could see this as having `batch_size * height` times a 1D convolution between two vectors of size `width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) regarding the tensor shape:

> The callable to be performed. It accepts one argument, which will have
> the same (possibly nested) structure as elems. Its output **must** have
> the same structure as **fn_output_signature** if one is provided;
> otherwise it must have the **same** structure as elems.

So try a more flexible output signature:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from functools import partial

A, B = tf.random.normal(shape=(2, 1, 8, 512, 1))

# Reshape tensors suitable for `conv1d`
A = tf.transpose(A, [1, 0, 2, 3])
B = tf.transpose(B, [1, 2, 0, 3])

# Define convolution function
conv_fn = partial(tf.nn.conv1d, padding="SAME", stride=1)

# Apply map
AB = tf.map_fn(lambda x: conv_fn(x[0], x[1]), (A, B), fn_output_signature = tf.TensorSpec((None)))
print(AB.shape)
# (8, 1, 512, 1)
```

You could also consider using `tf.while_loop`.